NestJS nested objects as query params + OpenApi documentation
I am using NestJS as backend and my use case is the following:
I would like to have nested objets as query params to filter on dates but on possibly several fields.
Exemple of url = GET /contents?createdBy=1&createdAt[startDate]=1234&createdAt[endDate]=1235&updatedAt[startDate]=5678&updatedAt[endDate]=5679
This would result in an object like this :
{
  createdBy: 1;
  createdAt: {
    startDate: 1234;
    endDate: 1235
  };
  updatedAt: {
    startDate: 5678;
    endDate: 5679;
  }
}

Here are my types for the moment:
export default class DateFiltersInput {
  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsNumber()
  @Expose()
  @IsOptional()
  startDate?: number | undefined;

  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  endDate?: number | undefined;
}


export default class GetContentsQuery {
  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  createdBy?: number

  @ApiProperty({ required: false, type: DateFiltersInput })
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => DateFiltersInput)
  @ValidateNested()
  createdAt?: DateFiltersInput;

  @ApiProperty({ required: false, type: DateFiltersInput })
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => DateFiltersInput)
  @ValidateNested()
  updatedAt?: DateFiltersInput;
}

But here is what I got in Swagger

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible in NestJS ?

Technically, a query string is, a string. Therefore Swagger will always represent it as a text input. If you want to pass an object structure, you'll have to use the body of the request, and since this is a GET request I don't think you do.
Consequently here is how you might go about passing a filter as a query string.
  /**Fetch a list of content records.*/
  @ApiQuery({
    name: 'filter',
    description: 'Filter json object',
  })
  public async getContents(
    @Query('filter') filter?: string,
  ): Promise<GetContentsResponseDto> {
    const filterDto = filter ? JSON.parse(filter) : null;
    return this.contentService.getContents(filterDto);
  }

Pass the query string as a stringified(JSON.stringify) object and JSON.parse it in the controller. In Swagger, you'll still get a text input but I use a site: https://onlinejsontools.com/stringify-json which helps me quickly stringify an object which I copy and paste in Swagger to test my endpoint quickly.
